# Не отображается окно PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Есть следующий код:

```
'''main.py'''
 import sys
 from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
 import main_window
 import success_window

class Bot(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, main_window.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.ui = main_window.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ship_info)

    def ship_info(self):
        success = SuccessWindow()
        success.show()

class SuccessWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,success_window.Ui_SuccessWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = success_window.Ui_SuccessWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Bot()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Файл success_window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_SuccessWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 150)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 150))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 150))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 161, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 100, 89, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", 
"MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data saved 
successfully"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))
```

Собственно вопрос. Почему не отображается окно SuccessWindow() при клике на pushButton_2 ? Никакой ошибки не возникает. Программа попадает в метод, но вот почему-то отображать не хочет, помогите.

Comment: Опубликуйте `main_window.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окно отображается на миг. Замените

```
success = SuccessWindow()
success.show()
```

на

```
self.success = SuccessWindow()
self.success.show()
```